# Opening a html page in iframe of one page from iframe of another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, target

### Page1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>page1</h1>
<iframe src="" name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

page1 contains the iframe1 which is empty and doesnt show anything in the beginning.

### Page2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>page2</h1>
<iframe src="opening.php" name="iframe2" id="iframe2"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

page2 contains the iframe2 which shows opening.php.

### opening.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="check.php" target="iframe1">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

opening.php contains a link which has href=check.php and

### check.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>alright</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to open check.php from opening.php which is shown in iframe2 in page2, in page1's iframe1. please help!!

Comment: then make a link to page1.php and load check.php in it's iframe (either hardcoded or conditionally depending on a $_GET var)

Comment: since page1 isn't loaded while you're at page2 it can not work that way you've tried.